# How do I spell out each inputted digits in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to make a program that takes an integer input and when you enter a number, it types out the spelling of each digit. For example, I inputted 12, the program will print out:
One
Two
I have a little problem with the code, how do I print out the results (or the spellings) vertically and in separate lines? The output should be:

```
Enter the number: 86
Eight
Six
```

But my output is:

```
Enter the number: 86  
Eight Six
```

I just need it to print vertically and in different lines like I said. Thank you! You can alter the code itself too, This is my code:

```
arr = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine']
 
def number_2_word(num):
    if(num==0):
        return ""
        
    else:
        small_ans = arr[num%10]
        ans = number_2_word(int(num/10)) + small_ans + " "
        return ans
 
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
print(end="")
print(number_2_word(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
ans = number_2_word(int(num/10)) + small_ans + " "
```

Use line break rather than space

```
ans = number_2_word(int(num / 10)) + small_ans + "\n"
```

I did a few tests, seems work as you expected